# How does FireEye HX work?

Tags: threats, insider-threats, end-points

Can someone please expand on how FireEye HX works, what does it do exactly? Here is the site info: https://www.fireeye.com/products/hx-endpoint-security-products.html, but it's written in such an empty language that should get a reward for saying something without saying anything.

Is it monitoring the incoming/outgoing connections? Is it looking for connection patterns?

Thanks

PS. There is no FireEye tag and I am not too sure what tags would be best for my post. I used threats & insider-threats for now.

Update: Found this thread: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/444856-has-anyone-used-fireeye-malware-protection-system

Comment: This is likely a better question for FireEye's sales folks and pre-sales engineers than it is here.

Comment: @Xander: Good point, but I was hoping that an user - perhaps from IT/IS - could explain why it would be so good to use it (I usually hate sales pitches when it comes to software). Also, I am just an individual, not sure they would talk to me. I guess I could pretend I am from a bigger company. The reason I asked the question is that it's going to be piloted at a friend's workplace.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you, and I completely agree.  I just think it's likely your going to get crickets here.   Hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I have the same questions - the website doesn't actually explain what the product is, other than to say we all need it. Would love to get some user feedback rather than dive into an adventure of slideshows with sales-folk... :-)

Comment: I work at FireEye and wanted to let you know that we have updated our solutions pages to include more relevant information on what our products are and how they can help you and your organization. Please take a look (https://www.fireeye.com/products/hx-endpoint-security-products.html) and let me know if you have any questions. I'd be happy to put you in touch with our endpoint team members.

Comment: @Helena: I went to the link. I like this one: "It expands endpoint visibility and provides contextual frontline intelligence". You guys should write speeches for presidents or for politicians. This type of writing reminds me of the communist times :-) I need to understand what the software does in terms of computer operations. Or perhaps it is a secret. The hackers could figure out what it does and they can find workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

its a security product that installs agents on endpoint to watch for any suspicious execution activity and alert you on it.

it can be used to push Indicators of compromise that are not covered yet by an anti-virus or an IPS.